# comparator for c++ sort function giving errors

Tags: c++, sorting, compare, stdvector

Following is solution of leetcode problem called Merge Intervals using compare function inside a sorting function

```
class Solution {
public:
static bool compare(vector<int> t1,vector<int> t2)
{
    if(t1[0]==t2[0])
        return t1[1]<=t2[1];
    return t1[0]<=t2[0];
    //return t1[0] < t2[0] || (t1[0] == t2[0] && t1[1] < t2[1]);
 }
 vector<vector<int>> merge(vector<vector<int>>& arr) {
    int n=arr.size();
    vector<vector<int>> ans;
    sort(arr.begin(),arr.end(),compare);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int start=arr[i][0];
        int end=arr[i][1];

        if(!ans.empty() && ans.back()[1]>=end)
        {
            continue;
        }
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(arr[j][0]<=end) //not arr[i][1]
            {
                end=max(arr[j][1],end);
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        ans.push_back({start,end});

     }
    return ans;       
    }
  };
```

Its giving error:

> Line 1037: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)
> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:1046:9

if the compare function only has

```
static bool compare(vector<int> t1,vector<int> t2){
    return t1[0] < t2[0] || (t1[0] == t2[0] && t1[1] < t2[1]);
}
```

this code runs fine,
but when

```
static bool compare(vector<int> t1,vector<int> t2){
    if(t1[0]==t2[0])
        return t1[1]<=t2[1];
    return t1[0]<=t2[0];
}
```

the error pops

> Line 1037: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)
> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:1046:9

Have tried to implement the same logic in the 2 functions. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have already found the solution! An order relation should use `<` (or `>`) but not `<=`. `compare(a, a)` should return false.